# Angularjs jQuery FIle Upload

Tags: node.js, angularjs, jquery-file-upload

I'm new at Angularjs and I'm trying to create an AngularJS project with [jQuery File Upload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/angularjs.html) but I could not distinguish between directives file controllers file and the view.

Can anyone help me by providing me a clear structure of how files should be placed? (controllers, directives, and view)

Comment: You can do a completely AJAXified upload without jQuery and only Angular :)

Comment: http://css.dzone.com/articles/angularjs-file-upload

Comment: @tymeJV 
how can i do an ajaxified upload without jQuery ? any suggestions ? links ? with only angular ? sounds great

Comment: Wish I was at home, could upload my repo, but for now, essentially, you make a directive that fires on an input file change, listen for the upload, use `encodeURI` on the file, use `$http()` from Angular to send a POST request back to your serv, `decodeURI` on server, and blamo!

Comment: @tymeJV thanks for the answer bro, i'm new at Angularjs and don't think i could handle all these informations alone :)

Comment: You'll love it, it's easy to pick up, just a different dev approach to take. Just remember that all DOM manipulation goes into directives, and your controller will handle the logic

Comment: @m.e.conroy is it possible to use the upload just in local (0.0.0.0:3000 ? ) without using ASP.NET MVC as the server-side platform. ?

for example : my upload page is : 0.0.0.0:3000/#/upload and i upload my files locally into this directory 0.0.0.0/#/upload/files/

Comment: @tymeJV Thanks for the informations, angular has a brand new vision of DOM, unlike Jquery, after a little search i found this solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20064991/how-can-we-upload-a-file-in-angularjs?rq=1

is the factory integrated with the controller or the directives ? because i have separed controllers and directives each one in a file and views also and my index.html is calling all the js scripts

Comment: Your factory is your services, they can be injected into your controllers and directives as you see fit, so any controller can have any factory. As per your comment above, the actual saving of uploaded files is configured on the server-side. The clients only job is to get the info back to the server.

Comment: @user3099273 The backend shouldn't matter where AngularJS is concerned, I use PHP personally.  What matters is how you program the backend to receive the file.

Comment: @tymeJV@m.e.conroy
i'm really stuck in here and need some inspiring code examples

Comment: @tymeJV i need your help on doing that in the right way. thanks a lot

Comment: Also look out for yoeman project. It has generator for angularjs. This give good structure to your angular app.

Comment: You can use this angularjs module: [angular-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload) which is pretty simple, light-weight and super easy to set up. Check out the [Demo](http://angular-file-upload.appspot.com/) page. It is cross-browser, support file progress/cancel, preview, multiple files and drag and drop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote something for my very first Angular.js project. It's from before there was an Angular.js example, but if you want to see the hard way, you can have it. It's not the best, but it may be a good place for you to start. This is my directives.js file.

```
(function(angular){

  'use strict';

  var directives = angular.module('appName.directives', []);

  directives.directive('imageUploader', [

    function imageUploader() {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link : function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
          var $imgDiv = $('.uploaded-image')
            , $elem
            , $status = elem.next('.progress')
            , $progressBar = $status.find('.bar')
            , config = {
                dataType : 'json',
                start : function(e) {
                  $elem = $(e.target);
                  $elem.hide();
                  $status.removeClass('hide');
                  $progressBar.text('Uploading...');
                },
                done : function(e, data) {
                  var url = data.result.url;
                  $('<img />').attr('src', url).appendTo($imgDiv.removeClass('hide'));
                  scope.$apply(function() {
                    scope.pick.photo = url;
                  })
                  console.log(scope);
                  console.log($status);
                  $status.removeClass('progress-striped progress-warning active').addClass('progress-success');
                  $progressBar.text('Done');
                },
                progress : function(e, data) {
                  var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
                  $progressBar.css('width', progress + '%');
                  if (progress === 100) {
                    $status.addClass('progress-warning');
                    $progressBar.text('Processing...');
                  }
                },
                error : function(resp, er, msg) {
                  $elem.show();
                  $status.removeClass('active progress-warning progress-striped').addClass('progress-danger');
                  $progressBar.css('width', '100%');
                  if (resp.status === 415) {
                    $progressBar.text(msg);
                  } else {
                    $progressBar.text('There was an error. Please try again.');
                  }
                }
              };
          elem.fileupload(config);
        }
      }
    }
  ]);

})(window.angular)
```

I didn't do anything special for the controller. The only part of the view that matters is this:

```
    <div class="control-group" data-ng-class="{ 'error' : errors.image }">
      <label class="control-label">Upload Picture</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="file" name="files[]" data-url="/uploader" image-uploader>
        <div class="progress progress-striped active hide">
          <div class="bar"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="uploaded-image hide"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: what about the controller.js and the html view ?? thanks